# Is it a bug when only porfolio line is visible in graph?

Tags: anychart

[image]

Only portfolio line is visible at start,is there any explanation for this, pls resolve this if its a bug.(for anychart team)

Comment: whats the issue with the question if you can explain rather than a downvote.

Comment: can this be reproduced in the original sample application or it happens on your side?

Comment: @AnyChartSupport i have downloaded latest sample from github, and this happened in the sample.

Comment: the image shown above is from your sample applicaiton

Comment: we've reproduced the problem and will try to fix it and report back when we have a solution

Comment: @AnyChartSupport ok thanks, it would be very helpful if you could resolve this asap.I am waiting for it.